# How to fix Visual Studio 2022 installation error in Ubuntu?

Tags: server

I am using Ubuntu and trying to install Visual Studio 2022 in my PC. During the installation, it takes a lot of time or something it shows installing error.

I got the error: “Couldn't install Microsoft.NetCore.HostPath.”

Are there any solutions?